# Give external parties access to web servers behind the firewall

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall, tunnel

I work in an AM-project as a consultant against three customers. We have a file server and a TFS server where all project related are saved. The problem is that it is behind the corporate firewall (which is managed globally outside my control), so the customers can not access our servers.

To solve this, each night we replicate the most important files to a cloud server, so that customers can login and access the files. However, it only one-way synchronization, so the clients can not edit the files. Additionally, they can not access our TFS server

I'm looking to maybe use VPN, but when I do not have control over the firewall, I can not see that it is possible for me. Or?

So my question is if there is any technique we can use to give customers a safe way in to our servers. It is enough that they only have access to the web server so that they can access the document management system and TFS

Comment: You really should have, and need to talk to your sysadmins about this. Especially since your profile reads 'nuclear power plants'. If the security is there for a reason , the best people to talk to are the people running the security.

Comment: I'm too afraid to answer this question because of the possibility that a possibly errant answer might be a contributing factor to a nuclear incident in Sweden.

Comment: You're probably right that I should talk to the security manager at my company, no matter how we choose to do. But before I talk to him I want to know if it is even possible to solve in a safe manner and what options I have.